# Debugging tools for performance of web application

Tags: performance

I have a web application developed in ASP.NET 2.0 ,deployed in a dedicated server. Now my pages taking long time to load. I want to debug the root cause.

I have checked the code level performance bookmarks and nothing found wrong there. Is there any tools to debug this? Something like analyzing the execution plan of an SQL query in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yslow

would be a nice choice

> YSlow analyzes web pages and suggests
>   ways to improve their performance
>   based on a set of rules for high
>   performance web pages.

For SQL performance issues take a look at

[SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

> Microsoft SQL Server Profiler is a
>   graphical user interface to SQL Trace
>   for monitoring an instance of the
>   Database Engine or Analysis Services.
>   You can capture and save data about
>   each event to a file or table to
>   analyze later. For example, you can
>   monitor a production environment to
>   see which stored procedures are
>   affecting performance by executing too
>   slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with recording and analyzing the relevant performance counters. a good stating point is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998583.aspx.